# How to append data to a component with useAsync hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-async

I am using react-async to fetch data from api like this:

```
import {useAsync} from 'react-async'

const getOrders = () => ...

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync({ promiseFn: getOrders })
  if (isLoading) return "Loading..."
  if (error) return `Oopsi`
  if (data)
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    )
  return null
}
```

Now, how do I update `data` (append the next responses to it)?
Should be something like this:

```
import {useAsync} from 'react-async'

const getOrders = (page) => ...

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync({ promiseFn: getOrders, page: page })

  if (isLoading) return "Loading..."
  if (error) return `Oopsi`
  if (data)
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
        <button onClick={() => {
                setPage(page + 1);
                getOrders()
                }>Get more orders</button>
      </div>
    )
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not built in to React Async. The only way to do it is by keeping your own record of the data (using a separate `useState`) and updating that in the `onResolve` handler for React Async.

I've setup an example for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-async-pagination-og13b

There's already an issue to track this feature request: https://github.com/async-library/react-async/issues/103